# How to compile custom ops in tensorflow without having to dynamically import them in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I checked through tensorflow documentation and they seem to only give information about compiling a custom op through a bazel rule:

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "zero_out.so",
    srcs = ["zero_out.cc"],
)
```

Once bazel builds it, you get a zero_out.so file which you can import into python like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
zero_out_module = tf.load_op_library('./zero_out.so')
```

Is there anyway you can link custom_ops during the bazel build of tensorflow so that you don't need to manually import custom ops through tf.load_op_library?

Comment: because tensorflow custom ops are coded in c++ and compiled through the cc_library rule in bazel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no officially supported extension point to pull in your own ops other than dynamically loading them.

If you build tensorflow from source and are willing to hack it it's not hard to pretend your ops are core ops, but it's not supported.